# Trigger click event of an ionic3 element programatically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, ionic2

I am trying to trigger the (ionic) click event of an element manually, from jquery or native dom events.

Let's say for example I have the following:

entry.html

```
<button [id]="id" (click)="entryClicked()></button>
```

entry.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'entry',
  templateUrl: 'entry.html',
})
export class EntryComponent {
  constructor() {}

  id = "entry_1"

  entryClicked () {
    console.log(id +" has been clicked")
  }

}
```

From another service, I would like to trigger the click event on entry_1.

**Problem:** this other service is completely separate from the first, it's a provider and to my knowledge, I cannot use `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` from it. So I cannot directly access functions of the `entry` component.

externalService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Injectable()
export class ExternalServiceProvider {
  constructor( ) { }

  someEvent () {
    $("#entry_1").click();
  }

}
```

Triggering `someEvent()` doesn't trigger `entryClicked()` like I hope it would.
It's not a problem of loading, the #entry_1 element is found by jquery. It's just that the `(click)` event bound to the element by ionic doesn't seem to be related to the jquery click event.
Same problem if I use `$("#entry_1")[0].click()`.
However, if I click the element in the page, it fires properly.

How can I fire the original ionic click event from the DOM, with or without jquery?

Comment: and why on earth you want to this weird stuff? Is there a end goal behind this?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari: I want to access the method of the `EntryComponent` from the `ExternalServiceProvider`. I don't see any way to do that otherwise (and would love to have another solution). The entry is created by an automatic synchronization in the database, and therefore I don't have access to the Component from the entry creation callback.
Not sure I'm very clear, but believe me, I tried finding better ways to do that, and redesigning a, by many aspect well designed app, just for this improvement is not worth it.
The click workaround would be a very good option at the moment.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari: The end functionality I'm trying to provide, is to do something on an entry that is just newly created by the user. The only way I can know an entry is **newly** created is from the callback of the creation of this entry.
As I mention in the previous comment, this callback is in a Provider that doesn't have access to the Component's methods, since I can't use ViewChild from a Provider.

Comment: Why don't you use Event?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari: thanks that's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Ionic Events to achieve this as described [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/#events).

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

Modify your code like this:

externalService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ExternalServiceProvider {
  constructor(public events: Events) { }

  someEvent () {
    this.events.publish('triggerClickEvent', "triggerClickEvent");
  }
}
```

entry.ts

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'entry',
  templateUrl: 'entry.html',
})
export class EntryComponent {
  constructor(public events: Events) {
    events.subscribe('triggerClickEvent', (data) => {
      console.log('Event triggered' , data);
      this.entryClicked();
    });
  }

  id = "entry_1"

  entryClicked () {
    console.log(id +" has been clicked")
  }
}
```